# web crawler word counter

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am using a simple text editor and CMD to run my python code i have tired building a web crawler which would go to a website and pull up all the words from it but when i run it in cmd it shows no word and no error and it  ends. Here is the code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import operator

def start(url):
    word_list =  []
    source_code = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser')
    for post_text in soup.findAll('a',{'class':'Index_singleListingTitles'}):
        content = post_text.string
        words =  content.lower().split()
        for each_word in words:
            word_list.append(each_word)
    clean_up_list(word_list)


def clean_up_list(word_list):
    clean_word_list = []
    for word  in word_list:
        symbols = "!@#$%^&*()_+:\"<>?,./;[]-="
        for i in range(0, len(symbols)):
            word = word.replace(symbols[i], "")
        if len(word) > 0:
            print(word)
            clean_word_list.append(word)

start('http://www.ebay.com/')
```

Comment: Seems like your `soup.findAll` does not find anything. There just seems to be no element with that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run the code and as pointed out by tobias there is no tag with the `Index_singleListingTitles` class. I don't know what you're looking for exactly but try looking at the ebay page source code with google developer tools or just a text editor and see if you can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Read about HTML tags and attributes. Then read the source page of the website from where you are trying to pick up the words.

```
flag_finder = BeautifulSoup(get_with_cookie, "html.parser")
    for tag in flag_finder.find_all('h2', attrs = {"class": "secret_flag"}):
```

Above, I am trying to capture *flags* from the HTML page loaded by *get_with_cookie* with tag = *h2* and attribute class = *secret_flag*.